# Is there anyway to deploy app from Travis to Amazon ec2?

Tags: java, shell, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, travis-ci

I want to deploy my app to Amazon ec2(Ubuntu instance) when my tests will be succeed.

1-)I have git hub repository which also a project and travis.yml.

2-)Travis can check my project and it succeed.

3-)When it succeed,a shell command should deploy my app to amazon ec2.(Confused Step)

I have learnt these but i can't do anything to
I know in travis.yml file should be like:

I know some answers but I couldn't solve. These are solutions to my problems.

```
after_success:

    curl --ftp-create-dirs -T uploadfilename -u $FTP_USER:$FTP_PASSWORD ftp://sitename.com/directory/myfile
```

In this solution,I can't find my ftp_user and password,if i know them,is it possible to transfer data with using **scp**.

And the other solution is:(using pem file)

```
after_success:

     scp -i "[pemFileName].pem" [A File] [hostname]@ec2-02-50-258-231.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com:~/.
```

The code written after "after_success" is working from terminal but the problem in here is i can't upload my pem file to Travis.And i don't want to push pem file to github.(For security)

**Briefly problem:** How can i deploy my app to Amazon EC2 when my test succeed on travis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Travis has the ability to encrypt/decrypt files stored in your git repository. You can store an encrypted version of your private key needed to `scp` into your EC2 instance.

See https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/encrypting-files/.

In my case I use a Bash script that, if the right conditions are satisfied, (1) decrypts the file according to Travis' instructions; and then (2) `scp`'s the build over to the EC2 instance using the decrypted .pem key.

Note that your `scp` command should incorporate some way to deal with `StrictHostKeyChecking`. This will disable it entirely:

`scp -i [path/to/id/file] -o StringHostKeyChecking=no [source] [destination]`

Though a more secure route is to get the host key fingerprint (e.g., `ssh-keyscan [host]`) and use as part of the `scp` command:

`scp -i [path/to/id/file] -o UserKnownHostsFile=path/to/custom/known_hosts [source] [destination]`